# How to fill a Rectangle based on needs

Tags: wpf

I'm making a border with Rectangle on all sides. as the borders are so thin the user is not able to put the mouse on it. so I decided to fill with 2 colors so the user will see a small border and it will have more space to place the mouse. so the problem, when I'm filling the corners, I'm not able to fill the L shape. i need to fill topLeft rectangle in L please take a look at the image

**Based on question**

**Why do you want to draw separate rectangles yourself?**

as the window style will be none I'm writing a custom resizing I want which side I got the mouse. based on that writing resizing events.

[image][image]

The black boxes has to fill with yellow

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Grips -->
        <!-- Sides -->
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="bottom" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="left"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="right"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="topLeft"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >

        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomLeft" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomRight"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="top" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize"  >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Name="topRight"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <!--Content-->

    </Grid>
```

Here are the 3 borders. how can I fill in that L shape thank you

Comment: Can you provide a mockup image of what you need? Also, please provide an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Alex please read the entire question it is MCVE. just how to fill rectangle in l shape just check the image u will understand what I mean thank you.

Comment: Please provide the full code of the xaml file. With just this it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira can please take a look at the image you will understand my problem in topLeft i need to fill yellow

Comment: I have already looked. and I'm trying to help you, but just pasting this code is not enough, in the image you have a Grid that is not in the code. If you really want us to help you have to help us too.

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira please take a look the entire grid .

Comment: Yes but we need the whole code to try this in our computer and help you. With just that piece of code isn't enough.

Comment: With just that code we can't reproduce your problem. You want help or no?

Comment: the grid is more than enough I just need to fill a corner and I don't have any code that the whole code.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the picture you posted.

Comment: There is no L for me, the corner is just white, no yellow overlap.

Comment: can u please <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition> to 10 and check the corners

Comment: if I will fill the entire corner with yellow it looks weird so I need to fill that part as a corner.

Comment: `There is no L for me, the corner is just white, no yellow overlap` i have removed the column spans basically i need to fill those corners like corners

Comment: Oh, *that* is what you want. Wow... I thought you wanted something else. Is there a reason you create those problems for yourself? Why not make it full yellow, instead of yellow with a white line? Your cursor will appear on the white as well and it will look funny.

Comment: for that, these guys need only 1px border if have given1px its hard to place mouse so they need more space to place mouse has to look like 1 px border only

Comment: application is on white so it will merge or I will use transparent something like that. I need to fill it so that it looks 1px border and more place to place the mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New solution, try like this and compile to see if it works:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Grips -->
        <!-- Sides -->
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="bottom" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"    Grid.Column="0" Name="left"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" Width="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="right"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="topLeft"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" Fill="#02FFFFFF" Panel.ZIndex="1" />

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomLeft" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomRight"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Row="0" Name="top" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" Fill="Yellow" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Name="topRight"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <!--Content-->

    </Grid>
```

Comment: I have made the top rectangle to fill both columns, and left rectangle to fill both rows, both rectangles with the size of 1 px.
Then, I changed the rowns and columns to be the size of 5px to make sure the corner is 5px and then in that corner add an almost transparent rectangle, to make sure is not visible for the user but at the same time to be clickable.

Comment: thank you so much for the effort I'm so sorry to say if I'm following this the bottom clickable area is on 1 px but it does what i asked so thank you i need bottom and top also 5 px

Comment: It's possivle, you can reproduce the same thing in bottom. Take a look at the code and try to understand and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another grid into the corner instead of a rectangle (orange to see what changed):

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="OrangeRed"/>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Fill="OrangeRed"/>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Fill="OrangeRed"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the corner mouse in that area, try this code instead.

The only change I made was setting the top corner to second column again, left corner to second row and filled your topLeftRectangle with the yellow color. Like this, that area can have different mouse:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Grips -->
        <!-- Sides -->
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="bottom" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="left"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="right"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="topLeft"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" Fill="Yellow" >

        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomLeft" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  Name="bottomRight"  MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="top" MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" Fill="Yellow"  />
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Name="topRight"   MouseEnter="DisplayResizeCursor" MouseLeave="ResetCursor" PreviewMouseDown="Resize" />
        <!--Content-->

    </Grid>
```

Comment: the border has to be 1px and mouse area has to be 5 px so that's why I have used the 2 colors  that whole point in doing this here the border size has changed sorry

Comment: Ok, check my new solution. But in this cases, you need to explain all of this details in your main question. Because if you don't explain all of this details, is very difficult for anyone to help you.